# How to prevent client data fetching with nuxt 3?

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

The only solution I found was to use a tag a or  so that the data is exactly requested from the nuxt server, but this created a new bug: when using window.history.back() or useRouter().back() I get an error:

[image]

Questions, how to globally prevent the primary page data from being fetch from the client?

The idea is to make access to each page the same way as it happens with the "a" tag, preventing data request from the client and without transition view, and after receiving the primary data for the page from the server nuxt - already execute the code on the client

Comment: Why use Vue at all if you want an MPA behavior? Use PHP or AstroJS. Seems counter-intuitive to have server-only requests while using a front-end meta-framework.

Comment: That's the question, I don't want to use php, after all nitro is a great technology, but the idea is just to get the initial page markup and after hydration for the client to request the data

Comment: Then, just use Nitro and put a wrapper around it with some vanilla JS. Nuxt and Nitro are not mandatory together.